# Alternative to "Download" as a PowerShell verb?

Tags: powershell, naming

I've got a PowerShell function `Download-File`, which uses `WebClient.DownloadFile` -- hence the name.

When I attempt to turn my `.ps1` script into a `.psm1` module, PowerShell warns me that "Download" is not in the list of [recommended verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060854/what-are-good-guidelines-for-naming-powershell-verbs).

What's a good alternative? `Get-` seems to be about getting properties, rather than contents (apart from `Get-Content`, oddly). `Receive-` seems a bit too passive for my liking (i.e. the script blocks until the information is sent) -- which doesn't fit well.

Ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me, 'Get' is the most natural verb. It gets everthing, not just properties. For the noun I would use something like 'WebFile', you can easily guess what you get and where it is coming from.

Comment: I agree with the OP, `Get` gets basic information **as a PS `object`**, I've never seen it used to save data to disk or persist it in any way. For instance `Get-ChildItem` gets information about a local or remote resource, it doesn't copy that resource to disk, that would be `Copy-Item`.

Answer (score 9):

Wouldn't this work:

```
 Start-Download -Url http://blah/
```

Or use `Invoke-Download`, as per the recommendations for synchronous operations. `Start` is for asynchronous.

Comment: Nide idea in general, but this is actually in the context of `Download-TeamCityArtifacts`, where `Invoke-DownloadTeamCityArtifacts` starts to look clunky.

Answer (score 1):

The full list is here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.2

There is no *prescribed* synonym for download.
`Copy` is the closest I've found, being documented as a synonym of the unapproved `Clone`.

There are also `Read`, `Save`, `Sync` and a whole bunch of others.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a better answer here. I know this is an old thread, but I don't agree with using the `Get` verb if the file you are download is going to be stored on your disk. I think `Get` should be reserved for truly read-only operations. It is okay to `Get` a file from the internet and store it into memory so that you can do something with it later, but the second you jot that file down to the disk, it is no longer a read-only operation.

I think that `Save` might be be best general purpose replacement for `Download`.

That could produce something like: `Save-WebFile -Uri $Uri`

Answer (score 0):

What about `New-Download` or `New-WebDownload` or `New-DownloadFile`??

Comment: Sounds like it's creating an object or a job, rather than actually downloading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Request-TeamCityArtifacts`?

Answer (score 0):

Following the pattern from `Invoke-WebRequest`, I would use `Invoke-ArtifactsDownload`. It's okay to keep the name tight and allow *some* of the context to come from the module name.

For example, I'm currently working on a SharePoint integration and came to this question because I wanted to name a function for downloading list item attachments. I got confused when `Get-PnPListItemAttachment` didn't retrieve the filenames but actually **downloaded** the files to the disk, so `Get` doesn't fit my expectations here, just as the OP said. However, the meaning of `PnP` isn't obvious without knowing the library name, and such ambiguity is fairly common when working with modules.

Comment: "Artifacts" may not be obvious, depending on your design domain. Use the language of your end users.